# How to create a dynamic class in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to migrate a project from JavaScript to TypeScript. I'm attempting to use the following code.

```
// CustomError.ts
class ErrorType {
    defaultMessage: string;
    errorName: string;

    constructor(defaultMessage: string, errorName: string) {
        this.defaultMessage = defaultMessage;
        this.errorName = errorName;
    }

    errorConstructor() {
        const {defaultMessage, errorName} = this;

        class CustomError extends Error {
            name: string;
            message: string;

            constructor(message: string) {
                super();
                this.name = errorName;
                this.message = message || defaultMessage;
                return this;
            }
        }
        return CustomError;
    }
}

export = {
    "InvalidThing": new ErrorType("Invalid Thing", "InvalidThing").errorConstructor()
};


// ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


// main.ts
// import CustomError from "./CustomError";
// const main = () => throw new CustomError.InvalidThing("Thing A is invalid.");
// main();

// other.js
// const CustomError = require("./CustomError");
// const main = () => throw new CustomError.InvalidThing("Thing A is invalid.");
// main();
```

The problem is I'm getting the following error.

> Default export of the module has or is using private name 'CustomError'.(4082)

Somehow I need to get `CustomError` to be in a higher scope. But the problem with that is that I need to be able to access that `errorName` & `defaultMessage`.

I'm also aware that I could just create a `CustomError` class for every error type. But in my actual code, I have roughly 8 error types. Which would mean a **LOT** of repeated code. I'd prefer to keep it DRY and not repeat a bunch of code.

How can I do this in TypeScript without errors?

---

You can also view a [TypeScript Playground with this code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/v2/en/play?removeComments=true&target=2&jsx=0&module=1#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-oDgaDwZDobD4YjkZDr0I3sQZFUOHwXrASkQ-NQI3WbJOoH4GEQoBFWGA2c2bRF5m9HxG8dUc162QAfFSMBrVRqy+zaFgJRa5ca1LrB1JQABBUCJSf6y1YW1VsB1lS9dRAA) to see the error it's throwing.

Comment: You may want to check https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html#generic-classes

Comment: @ilkerkaran It looks like this is only for types and can't be used for custom values. In this case, the `defaultMessage` and `errorName` are always strings. Those don't need to be generic types. But the values will be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ErrorType` class looks mostly superfluous to me - all it's being used for is to be able to create a `CustomError` instance with certain properties. To fix your problem, and to make the code much more concise, consider using a higher-order function instead, to which you can pass the `defaultMessage` and `errorName`, and returns a function that takes a message and returns a `CustomError` instance with the desired properties:

```
class CustomError extends Error {
    name: string;
    message: string;

    constructor(message: string, defaultMessage: string, errorName: string) {
        super();
        this.name = errorName;
        this.message = message || defaultMessage;
        return this;
    }
}
const makeError = (
    defaultMessage: string,
    errorName: string,
) => (message: string) => new CustomError(message, defaultMessage, errorName);
export = {
    "InvalidThing": makeError("Invalid Thing", "InvalidThing")
};
```

Because the `InvalidThing` property is now a plain function, call it without `new`:

```
throw CustomError.InvalidThing("Thing A is invalid.");
```

If the consumer must keep calling it with `new`, it's uglier since Typescript requires `new` targets to be classes or functions, which *cannot* return anything explicitly. For the currying sort of thing you're looking for to work, you'll have to have every value of the exported object be a new class:

```
const makeError = (
    defaultMessage: string,
    errorName: string,
) => class CustomError extends Error {
    public name: string;
    public message: string;

    constructor(message: string) {
        super();
        this.name = errorName;
        this.message = message || defaultMessage;
    }
};
const exportedObj = {
    InvalidThing: makeError('Invalid Thing', 'InvalidThing'),
};

throw new exportedObj.InvalidThing('Thing A is invalid.');
```

Comment: I realized that will work for the case I originally asked about, since it's all being used internally. I just realized that I have another case that is pretty similar, but since it is exposed as an API, I really don't wanna change the behavior to not use `new` since that would force all users of the library to change their use to remove the `new` keyword. So is there any way around this with my original question without changing what it exposes as the API?